# Radio button in datagridview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have data grid and I have two radio buttons in the datagrid i.e approve or reject and also one button in datagrid i.e  submit

what i want to do is when approved button is selected and submit button in the datagrid is clicked for one row I want the data of that row to be stored in the database with Isactive as 1 and the row should be deleted from the datagrid, but details must be stored in the database.

Similarly when the reject button is selected and submit button in datagrid is clicked,the data of that row should be stored in the database with Isactive as 0 and the row should be deleted from the datagrid

details must be stored in the database.

The is Active is not updating in the database

Can someone please tell me whats wrong in my code? The below is my C# code that i tried..

```
protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // *Get the Gridview Row* //
    DataGridItem drow = (DataGridItem)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;

    RadioButton rbpApprove = (RadioButton)drow.FindControl("rbtnapprove");
    RadioButton rbpReject = (RadioButton)drow.FindControl("rbtnreject");

    if (rbpApprove.Checked == true)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update table set IsActive= 0 where ARGID=@ARGID", conn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();        
    }
    else if (rbpReject.Checked == true)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update table set IsActive= 1 where ARGID=@ARGID", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }


    string empid = dgi.Cells[0].Text;
    string employeename = dgi.Cells[2].Text;
    string designation = dgi.Cells[3].Text;

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("insert into [table] values (" + empid + ",'" + employeename + "','" + designation + "')", conn);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First problem:**

```
if (rbpApprove.Checked == true)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update table set IsActive= 0 where ARGID=@ARGID", conn);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();        
}
else if (rbpReject.Checked == true)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update table set IsActive= 1 where ARGID=@ARGID", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

This block is not doing anything (or at least not what it should)

This bit: `where ARGID=@ARGID` is checking the database for entries with "@ARGID". I expect you were supposed to add parameters but forgot?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ARGID", /* The value to be checking for */ )
```

**Second problem:**

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("insert into [T_TADA_aaprovereject_groupdirector] values (" + empid + ",'" + employeename + "','" + designation + "')", conn);
```

This should be parameterised like the other 2 statements, to guard against [SQL Injection](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CEIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSQL_injection&ei=OGJAUvnyM4nDhAe0_4GAAg&usg=AFQjCNGcGZNbIk2jM8itxItHrCja7eJ0PQ&bvm=bv.52434380,d.Yms)

So I would suggest you change it to:

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("insert into [T_TADA_aaprovereject_groupdirector] values (@empid, @employeename, @designation)", conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@empid, empid)
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@employeename, employeename)
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue(@designation, designation)
```

Comment: Yes,I dont know how to put the value to be checking for...It should check the current row in the datagrid so sud it be cmd.parameters.addwith value("@ARGID",drow);...sorry if i am bad at this..but i am just learning..and I find datagridview really confusing..

Comment: I don't understand enough about what you're trying to do with the `isActive` database update to say whether it should be the datagrid row or not...

Comment: nope i have a row in the datagrid that contains name of employee designation and empid it also contains 2 radio buttons approve and reject and finally a submit button..all this is in the datagrid...so when i select on approve and click on submit I want Isactive to be updated as 1 and all those grid details must be saved in the DB...

Comment: So what else is in the table **table**? Just 1 field for *active / inactive*?

Comment: Inside table there are four fields employee,designation,empid and Isactive...So when user clicks on the radio button "accept" from the datagrid...All the details from the current row of datagrid should be saved in the database with Isactive as 1

Comment: So they are all being recorded in this table: `T_TADA_aaprovereject_groupdirector`? You have a different table in the `update` statement

Comment: no thats was by mistake i think i edited the question...its the same table...and yes it is recorded in T_TADA_aaprovereject_groupdirector..it should even be updated from T_TADA_aaprovereject_groupdirector..I just didnt want the table names to be seen so thats why mentioned T_TADA_aaprovereject_groupdirector as table...

Comment: Then you should be only updating existing records (not inserting new ones), and finding your record based on probably `empid`